# Multiple file processing in R, looping over variable for data processing

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I've written several functions for cleaning and processing 15 samples from the American Community Survey (ACS). This workflow is very laborious and repetitive: reading in each file, applying my functions, and moving on to the next survey year.

My current workflow is like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ids)
wage_2005 <- haven::read_dta("~/Data/ACS/2005_ACS.dta") %>%
  gen.wages(wage_2005) %>%
  reg.variables() %>%
  wage.adj(year = 2005) %>%
  wage.sample(year = 2005)
```

And moving on to 2006, 2007, and so on until 2019. For instance,

```
wage_2006 <- haven::read_dta("~/Data/ACS/2006_ACS.dta") %>%
  gen.wages(wage_2006) %>%
  reg.variables() %>%
  wage.adj(year = 2006) %>%
  wage.sample(year = 2006)
```

What I would like to is process each sample using my cleaning functions iteratively looping through the files in succession and using the year variable in each file in order to apply the appropriate processing for each survey year, and then get and store the result for each survey year in a list.

As a first step, I have written some code, reading in the files using an sapply function:

```
files <- list.files(path = "~/Data/ACS" , full.names = TRUE)

data_files <- sapply(files, function(x) {
  df <- haven::read_dta(file = paste0(x)), 
                USE.NAMES = TRUE, 
                simplify = FALSE
                }
)
```

But this takes an enormous amount of storage space as the files come from the Census bureau and are quite large. I am stuck on the next steps to iteratively process each file, apply my functions, and store the result in a list.

Some pseudo code to give a clearer idea:

- for year in years
- read in data file
- apply functions
- store results

Say for example that I have three sets of data, something like

```
acs_2005 <- 
  data.frame(id = random_id(n = 1000, bytes = 16, use_openssl = TRUE), 
             wage = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 100), 
             year = 2005)
acs_2006 <- 
  data.frame(id = random_id(n = 1000, bytes = 16, use_openssl = TRUE), 
             wage = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 100), 
             year = 2006)

acs_2007 <- 
  data.frame(id = random_id(n = 1000, bytes = 16, use_openssl = TRUE), 
             wage = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 100), 
             year = 2007)
data <- list(acs_2005, acs_2006, acs_2007)
```

And let's say they are to be read in as csv files

```
lapply(1:length(data_list), function(i) write.csv(data_list[[i]], 
                                                file = paste0(names(data_list[i]), ".csv"),
                                                row.names = FALSE))
```

My custom function is,

```
wage_summarize <- 
  function(df, year) {
    mutate(df, wage = case_when(
    year == 2005 ~ wage/0.7903,
    year == 2006 ~ wage/0.8112,
    year == 2007 ~ wage/0.8323)) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
      summarize(wage = mean(wage, na.rm = TRUE))
  }
```

How would I iterate through this list of data frames when the function depends on the year variable in order to perform the operation? In this case, hypothetically adjust for inflation?

Any help or guidance in this would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: This is a rather simple problem that you can solve with some `map`-type functions, especially `map2`. However, to give you a more clear answer, we need some `data` to work with. Could you reproduce your problem by using `simulated data` or the built in `data` like `mtcars`?

Comment: Yes, I've added some some simulated in my example! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should serve as a guidance for you with the information that you provided,

```
library(tidyverse)


# Simulate multiple data
# that has been loaded by some
# read_data-function
data_list <- list(
        mtcars,
        diamonds,
        iris
)


# Iterate through the list
# of data with some function
data_list <- data_list %>% map(
        .f = function(x) {
                
                x %>% mutate(
                        row_id = row_number()
                )
                
                
        }
)
```

Here we loaded the `data` and stored it in a list - it simulates that we read one data at the time. And we applied some function on using `dplyr`. It outputs a `list` of same length!

Please refer to [Programming with Dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for more information on implementing custom `functions` to your data.

If you want to do this in `parallel`, this is also possible - but this is OS-specific. If you are on `UNIX` then `mclapply()` is your go-to-function.

You asked for some guidance, and this is what I could provide with the information you gave.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that I would have to pass a list or sequence of the year variable to the map function in order for the custom functions to work, but is that not the case?

Comment: The beauty about `map` is that it takes almost any kind of arguments!

Comment: I tried this approach with my data but I got the error "Error in wage.summarize(.) : argument "year" is missing, with no default." The issue appears to be the fact that the year variable has to change for each dataframe in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just combine the list of dataframes into one -

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(data) %>% 
  mutate(wage = wage/case_when(
    year == 2005 ~ 0.7903,
    year == 2006 ~ 0.8112,
    year == 2007 ~ 0.8323)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(wage = mean(wage, na.rm = TRUE))

#  year  wage
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1  2005  63.0
#2  2006  61.9
#3  2007  59.8
```

Comment: Thanks! I mentioned that the files are quite large so this approach isn't practical for what I want. To be specific, the files all together take up ~ 11gbs of memory